# Why is findViewById undefined in my class?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a class and inside the class I try to call the `findViewById` method but I am getting an error saying `findViewById` is undefined.

I think I have to pass the `WebView` to `MyClass` or something but I have no idea on how to do that.

Here is the code i am working on:

```
public class MyClass {
   Context mContext;
    MyClass(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }
   ...
   WebView webview = (WebView) mContext.findViewById(R.id.myWebview);
   webview.loadUrl("mysiteUrl");
   ...
}

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     final myClass mc = new myClass(this);
     ...
}
```

I know that this is happening because `MyClass` does not extend an `Activity`. However I can get the `WebView` without extending `Activity`...

Please help! Thanks.

Comment: you are not extending your class from `Activity` or you are not using this method from an instance of a `View`

Comment: i already have a class that extends Activity and i declare myClass on that

Comment: Doesn't matter. This should be either directly in a class which extends `Activity` or called from an instance of a `View`

Comment: Then you need to pass Activity's content view to your class - this method is defined on Activity and View classes

Comment: You need to learn the basics https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Answer (score 0):

`findViewById` is a method that is defined by Android. Therefore you need to actually extend an Android `Activity` like so for it to recognise it as a method:

```
public class MyClass extends Activity {
```

and then import `Activity` when prompted.

If you want to utilise `findViewById` in a non-Android `Activity` then you can specify an `Activity` for it to find the view in like so:

```
WebView webview = (WebView) OtherActivity.findViewById(R.id.myWebview);
```

Comment: actually i already have a class that extends Activity and i declare myClass on that.

Comment: What do you mean 'I declare myClass on that'?. MyClass needs to extend Activity

Comment: @AndrewFielden I think he wants MyClass to be a standard Java class which is then utilised by an Android `Activity`.

Comment: i mean inside of my other class that extends Activity i put this code : final MyClass mc = new MyClass();

Comment: @muhammadsappe Maybe you'll want to create a constructor in MyClass and then pass in either the Context or the Layout.

Comment: @muhammadsappe Add the code to your question so I can see please.

Comment: @muhammadsappe Try passing `getApplicationContext()`.